# Concurrent Calculations in Java

Tags: java, concurrency

I have a bit of homework, and would like a little help.  I am trying to get my computer to concurrently calculate 5 sums at once. I know I should use threads, but not sure of the best way to implement this.

Sorry for not posting code here is what I have so far.

Main:

```
package CoddingEx;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        (new Thread1()).start();
        (new Thread2()).start();
    }
}
```

thread 1:

```
package CoddingEx;
public class Thread1 extends Thread {

    public void run() {
        int answer = 0;
        int input = 5;

        answer = input*5;
        System.out.println("Value of calculation 1: " + answer);
    }

}
```

thread 2:

```
package CoddingEx;

public class Thread2 extends Thread {

    public void run() {
        int answer = 0;
        int input = 5;

        answer = input/5;
        System.out.println("Value of calculation 2: " + answer);
    }

}
```

These are the first 2 calculations, going to stick with these 2 till I am sure this is the right way to do it.  My goal is to get all the threads to calculate and finish at the same time.

Thanks

Comment: Have u tried anything?

Comment: Did you read the chapter on concurrency and threads?

Comment: [this link](http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/07/java-thread-example.html#ai) may help buddy :)

Comment: I'd recommend writing the method that calculates a single sum, test it, get it working, then worry about five threads running simultaneously.

Comment: If you just want to do sums, your computer can do them concurrently already.  It can perform up to 3 instructions in the same clock cycle without you having to change your code.  If you want to use multiple thread I suggest you make sure each task takes at least 10 micro-second otherwise you can find that the overhead of using multiple threads means your tasks are slower (and more complicated) than using one thread.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I think its just a task to get us used to threads

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to use an ExectorService, but since this is an exercise you might need to set some shared fields/object and `join()` the threads to await for the results.  For your own interest, you might like to time with System.nanoTime() how long this takes with just one thread and with 5 threads as the results may surprise you.

Comment: @PeterLawrey thanks will have a look into exectorService as well

Answer (score 2):

If you are using JDK 7+, you should use Fork/Join Framework. I have used it and its main advantages are scalability and you learn how to think in parallel. Also, Threads seems to be low level compared to F/J framework.

Details about it : http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/papers/fj.pdf

Starting point: http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaConcurrency/article.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom Thread which accepts the numbers to be added together. In the `run()` you do the addition and store the sum somewhere.

Since you need five threads, you need to create five instances of this Thread and call `start()` on  them.

Comment: Why ? Why threads ? Callable's are much better, it's a Runnable on steroids(can return whatever you want, i.e. the result).

Comment: I havent used callable. Need to look into it